# Spring core 3.2.2 + Spring security 3.1.4: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-security

When I added Spring-security 3.1.4 next to Spring 3.2.2, I've got this ugly exception below. I googled it up and got only this link about the same error:
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?133706-Spring-3-2-0-RELEASE-breaks-with-JBoss-7
pointing to spring JIRA explaining that spring-asm is now in spring-core.
https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10134

I figured I need to exclude spring-asm from spring-security somehow.

Here is the exception I had:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer$ParameterNameDiscoveringVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2895)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.inspectClass(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:112)
org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:85)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:193)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1051)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:955)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Then I found this:
http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-asm-dependency-issue-in-spring-data/
with a similar problem in spring-data. The exclusion in the pom.xml works just as well:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

I share the solution for others who get the same error!

Comment: I figured you need to exclude spring-asm from spring-security.

I had this same issue whenever I was not using Maven.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that Spring Security 3.1.4 depends on Spring 3.0.7, so it ends up pulling in spring-aop 3.0.7, which pulls in spring-asm 3.0.7. What you want to do is to use maven's `dependencyManagement` section to force any Spring inclusions to use the latest version, like so:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- etc... 
          -- enumerate all Spring sub-projects here that spring-security includes 
          -->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

You can verify that you've managed away all the dependencies by running `mvn dependency:tree`.

For example, before `dependencyManagement`, my `mvn dependency:tree` output was:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 3.0.7.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
```

Notice in particular the first three lines, where `spring-aop` brings in `spring-asm`. After adding sufficient `dependencyManagement` declarations, we now get:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 3.0.7.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 3.0.7.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 3.0.7.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 3.0.7.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 3.0.7.RELEASE)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 3.0.7.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 3.0.7.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 3.0.7.RELEASE)
```

Notice how `spring-asm` is not even included anymore, since the new `spring-aop` does not require it.

This is a cleaner way to manage your Spring versions than the exclusions in the answer above, as it will apply to any other 3rd party dependencies you might add that reference Spring.

Answer (score 0):

**Add the following dependencies in the pom.xml:**

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>  
    <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>  
</dependency>  
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>  
    <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>  
</dependency>
```