# Spring Security java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError. Maven Dependency Management issue

Tags: spring, maven, jakarta-ee, dependency-management

Hi I searched this forum for getting the solution of the above problem and some one quoted that using maven's dependency management this kind of issue be rectified. But I generally do not much aware of spring dependency issues so I am posting this problem here.

```
java java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer$ParameterNameDiscoveringVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.jaggs.j2ee</groupId>
<artifactId>J2EEApp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>A Sample J2EE Application</name>
<description>A Sample J2EE Application</description>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>primefaces maven repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ant</groupId>
        <artifactId>ant-apache-log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

How should I utilize maven's dependency management to rectify the above issue. please help.
[here is reference for this kind of problem from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801639/spring-core-3-2-2-spring-security-3-1-4-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerro)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```