# IncompatibleClassChangeError: class

Tags: spring, maven

Error while deploying application on weblogic :

```
Could not load user defined filter in web.xml: com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet.
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer$ParameterNameDiscoveringVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
```

POM.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
    <version>${springSocialVersion}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
    <version>${springSocialFacebookVersion}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-twitter</artifactId>
    <version>${springSocialTwitterVersion}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-test</artifactId>
    <version>${springSocialVersion}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>${springSecurity}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>


  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${springVersion}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>${springVersion}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${springVersion}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>${springVersion}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${springVersion}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>${springVersion}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${springVersion}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${springVersion}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>${springVersion}</version>
  </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>${springDataVersion}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/16801639/934307?

Comment: What is your question?